# How to set read only property to entire Django forms based on session user

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have created a form that can be used to update/create/view records. When a user selects a record that record data is rendered in the form. So that user will able to view/edit the form. The problem statement here is that if a record is created by some other user then the session user will not able to edit (only the creator should have access to edit).

I am thinking to write a logic so that when the record is created by the session user then only he/she will edit. Otherwise, the user will just view the record using the same form.

Below is my view file

```
    current_blog = Blog.objects.get(pk=blog_id)
    init_dict = {
        "blog_title": current_blog.blog_title,
        "blog_description": current_blog.blog_description,
        "last_modified": current_blog.last_modified
    }
    form = NewBlog(initial=init_dict)

return render(request, "myblog/blog.html", {"new_blog": form})
```

form.py

```
class NewBlog(forms.Form):
blog_title = forms.CharField(label="Form Title", max_length=250, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={"class": "form-control", "placeholder": "Enter title here"}
))
blog_description = forms.CharField(label="Blog Description", widget=forms.Textarea(
    attrs={"class": "form-control", "placeholder": "Enter blog Description"}
))
```

blog.html

```
{% for field in new_blog %}
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                              <fieldset>
                                {{ field.label }}
                                {{ field }} <div class="text-danger">{{ field.errors }}</div>
                              </fieldset>
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is if you just want user to view the details then you dont need a form for that.you can just display the users data in p tag or heading tag.
secondly you can set readonly attribute of html input tag so users wont be editing it.

- YOu can add attrs={"readonly": "true"} // inside forms.py attr object
- or you can use jquery : $('input').attr('readonly', true);